# Unable to download a package using Pip : says Cython not installed when it is

Tags: python, installation, pip, cython

I am trying to download the [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/) package on my Windows 10 system using `pip`.
On my command line, I wrote-

```
pip install pyahocorasick
```

It gave the following output -

```
Collecting pyahocorasick
  Using cached pyahocorasick-1.1.4.tar.bz2
Installing collected packages: pyahocorasick
  Running setup.py install for pyahocorasick ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Krishna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-b7a1mq0t\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3iv3a5oc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    failed to import Cython: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    error: Cython does not appear to be installed

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Krishna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-b7a1mq0t\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3iv3a5oc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b7a1mq0t\pyahocorasick\
```

Then I tried to see if `Cython` is in fact installed, so I wrote-

`Cython version`

and the output was -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\cython.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

And finally I tried -

`install Cython`

And the output was -

`Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\python34\lib\site-packages`

**So my question is** - if Cython is already installed, why does installing the package pyahocorasick give the error - `Cython does not appear to be installed`? And how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think you have not installed proper version of Cython. uninstall it and install proper version. then try..

Comment: @JayParikh, but as you can see in the output of `install Cython`, it provides the right path for the Cython installed, right?

Comment: as i said, check if it is win32 or win64. i think uninstall and install proper version would work

Comment: ok. how can I check the architecture version of cython?

Comment: check this out http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html